# onkeyup event not working when focused on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a `div` I want to hide when I press F2... Everything works fine, except when the focus is on an iframe below this div...

```
<script> 
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;

function KeyCheck(){
   var KeyID = event.keyCode;
   switch(KeyID)
{ case 113:
   document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none" }
break;
}

</script>
```

But like I say, when focused on an iframe, this piece of script has no effect... Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `iframe` displays another HTML document. That means inside an `iframe` element exists another DOM structure totaly different than the one outside it. So question is, do you really need to use frames? There are other ways to display content in the `iframe` "fashion".

Answer (score 1):

```
//put this inside your frame
function keyPressHandler(e){
if(!e) e = self.window.event;
if(e.keyCode === 39){
        //do something awesome
}
}
top.frames.myframe.document.onkeyup = keyPressHandler;
```

This works with frameset, I haven't tested it yet using iframes